# getting strange formatting after doing excel formula

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a simple excel formula that has a number on A1 and for each row, it adds 1 to the total

```
Formula: =SUM(First Row Value + 1)
First Row Value: 5472611273010295
Expected Value: 5472611273010296
Actual Value: 5.47261E+15
```

How can I change the formatting to show the expected value? I tried rounding and that didn't fix it either.

Comment: A search for **Excel-specifications-and-limits** from Microsoft. Then under the heading _Calculation specifications and limits_ you can see the limits you are encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel uses only 15 digits of **number precision**

You may not be able to resolve this issue short of breaking your formula into parts, or using VBA.

For example if you put the first 8 digits into Column B and the Second 8 digits into column C, you can then create a helper row to do this for you.

```
Column B    Column C    Column D    Column E

54726112    73010295    =C2+1       =B2&D2

54726112    73010295    73010296    5472611273010296
```